# Realm where not contains in Java

Tags: java, android, realm, contains

If I have an array of primitive values, how can I run a .not().contains() on a .where() from RealmResults ?

The code would hopefully look like this:

```
 results.where().not().contains("id", new int[] {1, 2, 3})
```

Or do I have to iterate over all of these results and pluck them out individually?

Comment: Did you find a solution my dude?

Comment: The only solution I found was the answer I have just accepted, unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such method to query against the arrays as of now . The second paramater of contains() requires a string so you cant pass int[] or int . Iterating over the result is the only option .

```
RealmQuery q = users.where();
for (int id : ids) {
q = q.notEqualsTo("id", id);
}
RealmResults<users> users = q.findAll();
```

You can use between() if you need to query against a range of value .

Answer (score 3):

You can try beginGroup and then not in to query against the Arrays

```
realm1.where(UserModel.class)..beginGroup().not().
                    in("key",Your Array)).endGroup().findAll();
```

Comment: it doesn't need beginGroup()